# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'frame')

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework

I'm currently trying to animate a few frames from a spritesheet using Phaser3. The page successfully renders the first frame of the animation to the screen, but fails when I try to actually code in any of the animations.

Here's what I have so far:

```
export default class Intro_Animation extends Phaser.Scene
{
  constructor()
  {
    super('Intro_Animation');
  }

  intro(){}

  preload()
  {
    this.load.path = './src/assets/intro/';

    this.load.spritesheet('intro_frame', 'westwardJourney_02-Sheet.png',
  {frameWidth: 144, frameHeight: 130});
  }

  create()
  {
    //fails somewhere in the animations here
    var introAnim_config = {
        key: 'introWalkAnim',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('intro_walk', { start: 0, end: 23, first: 23 }),
        frameRate: 20,
        repeat: -1
    };

    this.anims.create(introAnim_config);

    //loads in first frame here
    this.add.sprite(250, 150, 'intro_frame').play('introWalkAnim');
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error message, or how does it fail?

Comment: Is the problem solved, or do you need some help?

Answer (score 0):

I just can assume, *without knowing the exact error message*, that the `frameWidth` and/or `frameHeight` is maybe too big *(meaning: bigger than the actual image size, **even for 1px is enough**)*. This could produce an error like:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'duration') ...`

and also show an image.

Except this, I don't know any other reason, how an error could occur, while displaying atleast a part of an image, and I tested *serveral* possibilities and combinations.