# Player does not move Phaser3 Learn

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

I'm learning by looking at page 6 of phaser3, but there's an error even if I do the same on the site. I can jump, but the left and right controllers have an error. Why is that?

How should I specify the type? I need your help, guys!

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'duration')

```
function App() {
  // ..
  let platforms;
  let player: any;
  let cursors: any;

  function preload(this:any){
    // ..
    this.load.image('dude', 'src/assets/dude.png', {frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48});
  }

  function create(this:any){
    this.add.image(400,300,'sky');
    this.add.image(0,0, 'star').setOrigin(0, 0);

    platforms = this.physics.add.staticGroup();;
    platforms.create(400,568, 'plane').setScale(2).refreshBody();
    // ..

    player = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 450, 'dude')

    player.setBounce(0.2);
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'left',
      frames:this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', {start:0, end:3}),
      frameRate: 10,
      repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'turn',
      frames:[{key: 'dude', frame:4}],
      frameRate: 20
    });

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'right',
      frames:this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('dude', {start:5, end:8}),
      frameRate: 10,
      repeat: -1
    });

    this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms);
    
    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    console.log(cursors)
  }

  function update(){
    if(cursors.left.isDown) {
      player.setVelocityX(-160);
      player.anims.play('left', true);
    } else if(cursors.right.isDown){
      player.setVelocityX(160);
      player.anims.play('right', true);
    } else {
      player.setVelocityX(0);
      player.anims.play('turn');
    }
    if(cursors.up.isDown && player.body.touching.down){
      player.setVelocityY(-330);
    }
  }

// ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the code seems to be correct, the problem could ***probably*** be caused because, the `frameWidth` and/or `frameHeight` of the image is maybe too big *(meaning: bigger than the actual image size, **even for 1px difference** is enough, to cause the error)*. This could produce an error like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'duration') ...
```

but it would still shows an image. Just check if the dimensions of the image *(the one loaded in the `preload` function)*, are multiple of the `frameWidth` and `frameHeight`.

> Based from this older answer *(https://stackoverflow.com/a/72067212/1679286)*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple typo, that I'm surprised wasn't caught by TypeScript:

```
function preload(this:any){
  // ..
  this.load.image('dude', 'src/assets/dude.png', {frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48});
}
```

You're loading it as an `image` but you should be loading it as a `spritesheet`.

```
this.load.spritesheet('dude', 'dude.png',
    { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 }
);
```